# How can I move installed apps from the old microSD card to a new one, as I swap the cards inside my phone?

Tags: applications, sd-card

In my Android phone, I have moved some installed apps from the internal storage to a MicroSD card. Now I swapped the microSD card with another microSD card inside the phone. How can I move the installed apps from the old to the new microSD card?

My phone is Kyocera Hydro Icon with Android 4.3. It seems to only have one microSD card slot and a SIM card slot inside. I can't find a second microSD card slot.

I can't move installed apps from old microSD card to my internal storage, because my phone doesn't have enough space.

Will it work if I copy the files from one sd card to the other, file by file, by connecting both microSD cards to a computer simultaneously:

- inserting one microSD card to a computer, via microSD-to-SD adapter, and
- inserting the other microSD card to the same computer, via keeping it inside the phone and connecting the phone to the same computer via USB cable?

Update: copy file by file from a sd card to another by connecting both to a computer doesn't make the phone work with the new sd card.

Comment: You said you swapped the microSD cards. Then later said you didn't find any microSD card slot on the phone. You are contradicting yourself. To move the apps: put the old card back on the phone. Move the apps from SD card to phone. Insert the new SD card, then move the apps from phone to SD card.

Comment: I can't move installed app from old microSD card to my phone, because my phone doesn't have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to read an image from one MicroSD card and write it to another.

First, specify image name and press `Read` button:
[image]

Then change sd card and press `Write` button:
[image]

Moreover, if there is more storage space on the second SD card, try using free [Paragon Partition Manager Community Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/) to resize partition (note, FAT32 limited to 32GB):
[image]